# How to show the filesystem of a logical volume (LVM)? (tldr:I/O error)

Tags: lvm

- How to show the filesystem of a logical volume (LVM)?

`lvdisplay` doesn't show them and fdisk isn't suitable to work with LVM.

- `ssm` tool shows some but not all:
  [image]
- `lsblk -f`

[image]

I'd like to know the `/dev/cl/root`'s filesystem (under /dev/sdc3 that is a physical volume).

Trying to mount one:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/cl-root /mnt/optiplex
mount: /mnt/optiplex: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/cl-root.
```

- `lvs`:
  [image]

I can't mount the root logical volume in this group volume:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lsblk` which shows all block devices, including (active) logical volumes, with `-f` it also shows filesystem type and other filesystem-related information.

Output example from my system with "standard" encrypted LVM setup with two LVs for `/` and `/home`:

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME                                          FSTYPE
...
└─nvme0n1p3                                   crypto_LUKS
  └─luks-dfcda59b-1322-4705-bb04-e09a72b2d678 LVM2_member
    ├─fedora-root                             xfs
    └─fedora-home                             xfs
```

If you have logical volumes that are not active, you can't get a filesystem type for them -- for inactive LVs there is no block device to read from so tools can't get a filesystem type from them (basically all tools that show filesystem use (usually indirectly) libblkid which reads first sector of the a device and compares it to a list of known filesystem signatures, so no block device means no filesystem information).

To get the information you want, you need to activate the LVs first, you can activate all LVs in the `cl` VG with `vgchange -ay cl`. (Of course this wouldn't work if the VG or the LV cannot be activated for some reason.)

Comment: It shows `LVM2_member` without expanding to logical volumes.

Comment: `LVM2_member` is the PV signature on the `sdc3` partition. I have updated my answer, you can't get filesystem information for inactive LVs -- there is no block device to read the superblock from.

Comment: Thank you, I enabled them `2 logical volume(s) in volume group "cl" now active` but `ssm` and `lsblk -f` still don't show them.

Comment: Do you see them in the `lsblk` output without filesystem or just not at all? Does the `/dev/mapper/cl-root` exist? What `lvs -a` shows?

Comment: yes, `/dev/mapper/cl-root cl-swap` and `/dev/cl/root swap` exist. Enabling the group volume doesn't change the screenshots in my question.

Comment: Interesting. The `mount` error makes me think there is something wrong with the `cl` VG (or the disk), do you see any I/O errors in the journal? What does `blkid -p /dev/mapper/cl-root` prints (`blkid -p` actually probes the device to look for a filesystem, `lsblk` uses cached data).

Comment: The `dmesg` log gave me a hint. For whatever reason, after a reboot, it works... (the disk is connected via an usb sata case and unplugging re-plugging it hasn't solved anything) Please update your answer with an I/O error. I bookmark this question for reference.